# Subscribing tags - Emails always arrives very late

Tags: feature-request

I have subscribed on several tags that I want notification on when new questions are posted, however the emails always arrive many hours after the question has initially been posted. This often leads to the questions have already been answered, thus rendering the feature kind of useless for me.

Is there any way to get immediate updates on new questions? That way I dont have to continually browse the new questions list in hunt for questions to answers.

Maybe a continuously updated RSS feed for every tag and combinations would be nice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Filtered Questions at [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com), create new filter and choose "every 15 minutes" in dropdown there. You will receive notifications within 15 minutes after question was asked.

Answer (score 3):

There do already exists rss feeds for every tag and question. They are of the form

- http://site.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag/tagname
- http://site.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/number

So, this meta question's feed is: https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/857
And the [feature-request](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag feed is: https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag/feature-request

You can also pull up a feed of some kinds of searches, multiple tags definitely work though tag and string may not. For instance, to have an rss feed of the tags [discussion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) and [qotw](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qotw) on this site, use the link: https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=discussion+qotw

You could, of course, do this on the main site by changing the host and interesting tags list on the url.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one was answered over on meta.so [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6557/154443) - sounds like this was a deliberate decision.

Comment: It looks to me like that meta.so post was for a different feature: the meta.so poster wanted an instant email anytime someone posted an answer to his question.  Jeff Atwood gave a reasonable explanation why that might not be good for the community.  But here Karrax is asking for an instant notification any time someone else posts a new question.  It seems to me that Karrax's requested feature would be good for the community, not bad.

Comment: Ahhh - I guess @Andrey's answer works then. Feature already exists :-)